# Filter a table that is dynamically filled

Tags: php, javascript

I have a table that has a sort option on my page. I am selecting the data for the table from a database using `SELECT` and `WHERE` now I know you can simply add `AND` after `WHERE` in the script to pull even less lines from the table.

I am needing the script to originally pull all the information from the table and then if the user uses the button to select a certain status the script runs again and only displays the tasks for that specific status.

Here is the button that will sort:

```
<div class="btn-group"> 
     <button class="btn">All</button> 
 <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
    <span class="caret"></span>
 </button> 
 <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
    <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">In Progress</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Done</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">New task</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Overdue Task</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the actual table script:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect();
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM affiliate_tasks WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]' ");

echo "<table class='table table-message'>
<tr class='heading'>
<td class='cell-title'>Tasks</td> 
<td class='cell-status hidden-phone hidden-tablet'>Status</td> 
<td class='cell-time align-right'>Due Date</td>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr class='task'>";
  echo "<td class='cell-ttle'>" . $row['task_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='cell-status hidden-phone hidden-tablet'>"  . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='cell-time align-right'>" . $row['due_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I am thinking that we would need to add something to this line but i'm not sure.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM affiliate_tasks WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]' ");
```

Is this a job for javascript? or is it something we can add to the php script?

What if instead of the button we did something like this:

```
<select id="sort-selection" class="btn"> 
 <option value="all">All</option>
 <option value="pending">Pending</option>
 <option value="in_progress">In Progress</option> 
 <option value="done">Done</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only pseudocode because your button is not part of form and there is no `$_POST` in your code and there is no info (in your code) what to add in query after `AND` (column_name = value)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM affiliate_tasks WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'";

if( isset($_POST['sort-selection'] && $_POST['sort-selection'] != 'all' ) ) {
     $query .= " AND status = '". $_POST['sort-selection']."';" ;
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Comment: This results in a Parse error. It is saying the } 4 lines in on your code here is unexpected.

Comment: it is only pseudocode, not full working code. There was no `;` after `selected_option`

Comment: So what do I need to do? that was my question.

Comment: Normaly you should put my code in place of your `$result = mysqli_query(...`. But there is not enought info in your code so I don't know what to put in place `button_was_pressed` and `selected_option`.

Comment: I updated my question take a look at that. Is that more along the lines of what we should do with the button?

Comment: It's better. But `select` needs name - for example `<select name="sort-selection" ... >` to get value `$_POST['sort-selection']`. I need also name of column in database keeping info about 'Pending', 'In Progress' etc. Do you keep this info as text or integer value ?

Comment: I keep the values as text and I can add `name="sort-selection"` to my select.

Comment: The name in the database that holds the status is called `status`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31217/discussion-between-user2371301-and-furas)

Comment: furas did you get my last message?

Comment: Put more info - error message. Have you try to add `print_r` and `echo` to see what PHP is doing (step by step) ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do that using Javascript, but you have to mark your rows while you're forming them in PHP, probably by adding a class for each row to indicate the status of the task it's displaying. And then in Javascript you just show/hide different classes according to your user input.